# Mono - Where is System.Printing.dll

Tags: mono

I am trying to send raw ascii data to a CUPS printer (raw queue) in a .NET application. My first thought was to use the classes PrintServer/PrintQueue/PrintQueueJob but running my application throws an FileNotFoundException for System.Printing.dll. If I understand the pages [Mono Status](http://www.go-mono.com/status/) and [Mono System.Printing in 4.0 vs MS.NET 4.5](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Printing) correct the System.Printing.dll and the classes are available in Mono. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can have a look at `System.Drawing.Printing`, it is mainly related the the 'old' Windows.Forms, but it does use Cups via the `libcups.so`... Checkout out `./System.Drawing/System.Drawing.Printing/PrintingServicesUnix.cs`

Comment: In the past, I have just lifted that code and placed it into my project as there are a number of `internal` and/or `private` Cups functions that are nice to have  and not exposed.

Answer (score 0):

That page is almost now useless, as Mono project migrates to a GitHub Markdown based new site,

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

System.Printing from .NET Framework uses too many Windows only APIs, so it does not make sense to bring it to Mono/Linux.

Another way to check compatibility is to directly check Mono source code,

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class

You can see there is no System.Printing folder.